# Setting asp.net chart axes scale to logarithmic

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, graph, charts, logarithm

I am trying to create a chart that has a base 10 logarithmic scale for both the X and Y axes. I keep getting the exception below when, I assume, the chart is bound.

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.DataVisualization.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Chart Area Axes - A logarithmic scale cannot be used for this axis.
>
> StackTrace:
>          at System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea.SetDefaultFromIndexesOrData(Axis axis, AxisType axisType)
>          at System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea.SetDefaultAxesValues()
>          at System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea.SetData(Boolean initializeAxes, Boolean checkIndexedAligned)
>          at System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea.ReCalcInternal()
>          at System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartPicture.Paint(Graphics graph, Boolean paintTopLevelElementOnly)
>          at System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartImage.GetImage(Single resolution)
>          at System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart.SaveImage(Stream imageStream)
>          at System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
>          at System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
>          at System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
>          at System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer)
>          at System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
>          at ASP.user_controls_test_controls_individualtestcontrol_ascx.__RenderPanel_Tables(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer) in C: (And so on........)

Here is the code for the chart in the front-end:

```
<asp:Chart ID="VoltageVsCurrent" runat="server" BackColor="AliceBlue" ImageLocation="~/Images/TempImages/ChartPic_#SEQ(300,3)" Width="600px" Height="400px">
    <Series>
        <asp:Series Name="Series1" ChartType="Point" LegendText="Current (A)" />
        <asp:Series Name="Series2" ChartType="Spline" LegendText="Spline" BorderWidth="2" />
    </Series>
    <Legends>
        <asp:Legend DockedToChartArea="ChartArea1" Alignment="Center" />
    </Legends>
    <ChartAreas>
        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
            <AxisX Title="Voltage (Volts)" TitleFont="Segoe UI, 12pt, style=Italic">
                <MajorGrid Enabled="false" />
                <MajorTickMark Enabled="true" />
            </AxisX>
            <AxisY Title="Current (Amps)" TitleFont="Segoe UI, 12pt, style=Italic" />
        </asp:ChartArea>
    </ChartAreas>
    <Titles>
        <asp:Title Text="Current vs Voltage" Font="Segoe UI, 16pt, style=Bold, Underline" />
    </Titles>
</asp:Chart>
```

And the code that sets the chart in the back-end:

```
VoltageVsCurrent.DataSource = ChartDataSource
VoltageVsCurrent.Series("Series1").XValueMember = VoltageColumn
VoltageVsCurrent.Series("Series1").YValueMembers = CurrentColumn
VoltageVsCurrent.Series("Series2").YValueMembers = CurrentColumn
VoltageVsCurrent.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.IsLogarithmic = True
VoltageVsCurrent.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisY.IsLogarithmic = True
VoltageVsCurrent.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.IsStartedFromZero = False
VoltageVsCurrent.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisY.IsStartedFromZero = False
VoltageVsCurrent.Series("Series1").IsXValueIndexed = False
VoltageVsCurrent.Series("Series2").IsXValueIndexed = False
VoltageVsCurrent.SuppressExceptions = True
VoltageVsCurrent.DataBind()
```

I added the `IsStartedFromZero = False`, `IsXValueIndexed = False`, and `SuppressExceptions = True` because of suggestions I found elsewhere while researching this problem. None of them seem to have helped.

I have checked that before the `DataBind()` the `ChartDataSource` had actual values in it, none of which were zero or negative. 
[An example of the ChartDataSource.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzvDC.png) (I know it's not logarithmic data, but it should still plot)

Any help is much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure you can do what you want to do. The `Chart Area Axes - A logarithmic scale cannot be used for this axis` leads me to believe you may need a different control. What that control is, I have no idea.

Comment: Then why would it be an existing property of the AxisX and AxisY which are the only relevant options for the chartArea

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15218249/using-logarithmic-scale-in-ms-chart-control) is pretty similar. Do any answers there help?

Answer (score 0):

One thing to watch out for is that one cannot take a logarithm of 0 (much like one cannot divide by zero). Therefore, if you have any points in your data that have an X or Y value of zero or less you will be unable to use logarithmic scaling.

Maybe try excluding any points where X <= 0 or Y <= 0.