# setting axis to logarithmic scale in MsChart keeps popping this error 'Chart Area Axes - A logarithmic scale cannot be used for this axis.'

Tags: vb.net, mschart

I'm writing this code in Vb.net to plot a function when I set the X axis (it represents the value t) scale to logarithmic I keep getting this error:

> (System.InvalidOperationException: 'Chart Area Axes - A logarithmic
> scale cannot be used for this axis.)

even though there is no negative values as you can see t ranges from 100 to tmax which is set to 100 000. when I try to set y axis to logarithmic scale it works.

```vb
Private Sub ButCalc2_3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles butCourbe.Click

    Dim q, stora, Transm, r, tmax, s, t As Double

    q = Val(txt_Q_w.Text)
    stora = Val(txt_S.Text)
    r = Val(txt_r.Text)
    tmax = Val(txt_tmax.Text)
    Transm = Val(txt_Trans.Text)

    chart settings

    rabatCou.SuppressExceptions = True

    rabatCou.Series.Clear()
    rabatCou.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Minimum = 100
    rabatCou.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Maximum = tmax

    Dim s_t As New Series

    s_t.Name = "Rabattement"
    s_t.MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Circle

    For t = 100 To tmax Step 100

        s = (q / (4 * Math.PI * Transm)) * well_func((r ^ 2 * stora) / (4 * Transm * t))

        s_t.Points.AddXY(t, s)

    Next

    rabatCou.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.IsLogarithmic = True
    rabatCou.Series.Add(s_t)
    rabatCou.Series("Rabattement").ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you seen this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15218249/using-logarithmic-scale-in-ms-chart-control

Comment: thanks for the reply, i did check this question but none of the responses helped me , kept getting the same error.

Comment: Are you sure you're not getting any non negative values?  It's hard to tell since you are doing a lot of math for the point `s` and we don't know all the variables.  Do a simple example where you just loop 100 times and increment a set value (say 1) value by 10 and see if it will let you chart the log scale for the x axis.  If it works that means you are getting values less than 1 in your series.  Also, setting the `AxisX.Minimum` just sets the minimum on the visible chart.  You can still add values less than 100 they just won't be visible because of your axis ranges.